# Windows 10 RDP randomly hangs then fast forwards

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

This post got kicked off of stackoverflow, so I am hoping this is a more appropriate place for it.

I have been having an odd problem for the past several of months that I have been unable to solve. I am using a windows 10 machine to remote into other windows 10 machines.

When using windows 10 to remote into windows 7 everything worked correctly. However, when the remote machine was replaced with a windows 10 machine the RDP connection has started randomly freezing. It will freeze for 10 to 15 seconds then any actions I took while I was frozen ( such as keys pressed or mouse locations clicked ) will replay in fast forward. This freezing happens pretty frequently, as often as every 10 minutes, or as rarely as once an hour.

I have tried a couple of registry tweaks suggested on the Internet for issues with RDP totally locking up the machine, however none of the symptoms totally match mine, and none of the solutions have worked.

I have a co-worker recently upgraded who has the same issue that I do. I have also tried remoting into the windows 10 machine from a windows 10 machine other than the one I normally use and the issue exists then as well.

I have tried remoting into a windows 10 "server" of mine from my main windows 10 workstation. It used to work pretty well, but now it just locks up and the RDP session has to be killed in task manager to regain control of the local computer. I am not convinced that this RDP issue is the same one I am having above, but it is similar.

Does anyone have an idea as to what I could try to fix this issue?

EDIT: I tried disabling passing through the smart cards as [mentioned here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/4w7in7/windows_10_and_rdp_freezingcrashing/), but it did not help.

I also tried turning off the new UDP functionality in the windows 10 RDP client. I'm not sure if it has helped the issue at all, but it has not fully fixed it.

EDIT 2: I ran wireshark, and the attached image seems to be the activity time frame that the issue occurred in.

I have tried disabling IPv6 on the network connection.  I have also tried disabling Energy Efficient Ethernet on my controller.

[Wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtcjM.png)

Comment: Yes I have an idea. This sounds exactly like network connectivity trouble. How are these devices connected to the network and are they local to each other or over the internet? A simple ping test is all it would take to see network interruptions that would cause this issue.

Comment: Try the manipulations described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1307813/8672), undo if they don't help.

Comment: @harrymc that posts suggestion does not seem to be having any affect on my issue.

Comment: Just an update on this issue.  It is still a problem, although over time with windows updates it has gone from once an hour, down to a couple of times a day.  So small improvements.

Comment: Another update.  I haven't noticed this issue on my machine for a week or more now.  The last idea my company has been targeting for the issue has been the SSD, there are many posts about how SSD write issues can cause glitching of this nature.  The last fix I recall trying was updating the drivers for my SSD.

Comment: Hi @JeremeGuenther I have also exact same issue on both Windows 10 PC (Remote & Local) If you find any solution then please post it here.

Comment: We do seem to have finally found a solution. I just posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many months of struggling through this issue, we finally seem to have it resolved.
We're not entirely sure what combination of the following items resulted in a fix, but these are the things we did.

1. Updated firmware for our SSD drives (reduced issue)
2. Disabled the new ability for RDP to use UDP packets (fixed issue)

   - This is done in the group/local policy editor by setting the "Turn Off UDP On Client" setting to Enabled.

We also had sporadic issues with the computer freezing locally as well as over RDP.  Not sure if this issue was related or not, but it eventually fixed itself, nothing we attempted seemed to fix that issue; we assume windows updates eventually took care of it.

This is a pretty common issue on windows 10 it seems, there are a lot of threads on the Internet trying to solve it; that is where these solutions came from for us.  We have tested it on a handful of computers for the last three months and they seem to be working well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue with network connectivity. For some reasons, TCP packets don't arrive at the destination, so the sender transmits them again. eventually, the receiver gets the packet, and everything after the missing packet, thus the "fast forward" effect.

You can investigate this by running Wireshark on the client or on the server, preferably on both.

Comment: That sounds logical. I have run extended ping tests and they have always been perfectly clean.

Comment: I have connected to the destination computer both over the internet and from another computer that is on the same local lan. They both have the issue

Comment: My coworker who is having similar issues says that his machine only does the fast forward thing when he is RDP d into it. But when he is local the machine just locks up briefly and randomly. Mine is a headless machine so I do not use it unless through RDP.

Comment: I tried running wireshark and included a screenshot in the post.  You seem to be accurate in your diagnosis.  I wonder if forcing UDP would be the answer, if that is even a possibility with RDP.

Comment: If it locks up briefly and randomly, then that may be the cause. It doesn't matter whether the packets are dropped on the network or the machine con't process them.

Comment: It's hard to blame the network though because it only happens with Windows 10, not windows 7. So what is different about windows 10 being the RDP destination that would cause this?

Comment: Maybe there is nothing wrong with Windows 10 RDP, just with this particular  computer.

Comment: That would not explain why this is a consistent problem in my company for every person who upgrades.
It could however be a hardware issue on the model of computer we have bought.  I'm trying to consider that angle as well.